# import .framework inside SPM (Swift Package Manager)

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

We are trying to integrate `TikTokOpenSDK.frameowork` (https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/ios_quickstart) within our custom `Swift Package`.

TikTok only gives us `.framework` access (you can download it manually). So far I've failed to integrate it, no matter what combination I'm trying, it fails with `unsupported extension for binary target ‘TikTokOpenSDK’; valid extensions are: xcframework`:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swift Package Manager only supports XCFrameworks. Your only option is to convert your classic framework into an XCFramework. I've [done this in the past for the SendbirdSDK](https://github.com/ezhes/sendbird-ios-xcframework) and everything worked out okay (though I can't give a full guarantee this will work for TikTok!). The gist of the process is that you want to create the XCFramework structure as described [here](https://github.com/spouliot/xcframework). Note that this was reverse engineered and so is subject to change.

This will involve quite a few folders if you want to make slices as compact as possible, but if you don't care at all and just need it to run on the simulator and on iOS devices the follow tree works:

```
TikTokOpenSDK.xcframework
- Info.plist
- universal-simulator
    - TikTokOpenSDK.framework
- universal-hardware
    - TikTokOpenSDK.framework
```

And then the aforementioned `Info.plist` should contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>LibraryIdentifier</key>
        <string>universal-simulator</string>
        <key>LibraryPath</key>
        <string>TikTokOpenSDK.framework</string>
        <key>SupportedArchitectures</key>
        <array>
            <string>arm64</string>
            <string>x86_64</string>
        </array>
        <key>SupportedPlatform</key>
        <string>ios</string>
        <key>SupportedPlatformVariant</key>
        <string>simulator</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>LibraryIdentifier</key>
        <string>universal-hardware</string>
        <key>LibraryPath</key>
        <string>TikTokOpenSDK.framework</string>
        <key>SupportedArchitectures</key>
        <array>
            <string>arm64</string>
            <string>armv7k</string>
        </array>
        <key>SupportedPlatform</key>
        <string>ios</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Once you've created this structure (and dropped in the original framework directly), you should be able to include this XCFramework in an SPM and it should work as expected!

Comment: Hey Allison, thank you so much! I was sure I commented on your answer but for some reason, it's not here haha. Just wanted to say huge thanks for the detailed answer - worked!!

Comment: @RoiMulia can you explained how did you make it work? I have the problem that I can't run TikTok framework on M1 simulator